# Error in php Connection Error: could not find driver

Tags: php, docker, api, postman

I got an error when I want to consume a Rest API using postaman and docker.
The error is marked in this line of code: Error in php `Connection Error: could not find driver`

```php
    <?php 
      class Materias {
        // DB stuff
        private $conn;
        private $table = 'materias';
    
        // Materias Properties
        public $clave_materia;
        public $nombre_materia;
        public $semestre;
        public $creditos;
    
        // Constructor with DB
        public function __construct($db) {
          $this->conn = $db;
        }
    
        // Get Materias
        public function read() {
          // Create query
          $query = 'SELECT *  FROM ' . $this->table;
          
          // Prepare statement
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
          // Execute query
          $stmt->execute();
    
          return $stmt;
        }
    
        // Get Single Materia
        public function read_single() {
              // Create query
              $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . 'WHERE clave_materia = ?';
    
              // Prepare statement
              $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
              // Bind clave_materia
              $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->clave_materia);
    
              // Execute query
              $stmt->execute();
    
              $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
              // Set properties
              $this->nombre_materia = $row['nombre_materia'];
              $this->semestre = $row['semestre'];
              $this->creditos = $row['creditos'];
        }
    
        // Create Post
        public function create() {
              // Create query
              $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' SET clave_materia = :clave_materia, nombre_materia = :nombre_materia, semestre = :semestre, creditos = :creditos';
    
              // Prepare statement
              $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
              // Clean data
              $this->clave_materia = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->clave_materia));
              $this->nombre_materia = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->nombre_materia));
              $this->semestre = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->semestre));
              $this->creditos = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->creditos));
    
              // Bind data
              $stmt->bindParam(':clave_materia', $this->clave_materia);
              $stmt->bindParam(':nombre_materia', $this->nombre_materia);
              $stmt->bindParam(':semestre', $this->semestre);
              $stmt->bindParam(':creditos', $this->creditos);
    
              // Execute query
              if($stmt->execute()) {
                return true;
              }
    
          // Print error if something goes wrong
          printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    
          return false;
        }
    
        // Update Post
        public function update() {
              // Create query
              $query = 'UPDATE ' . $this->table . '
                                    SET nombre_materia = :nombre_materia, semestre = :semestre, creditos = :creditos
                                    WHERE clave_materia = :clave_materia';
    
              // Prepare statement
              $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
              // Clean data
              $this->nombre_materia = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->nombre_materia));
              $this->semestre = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->semestre));
              $this->creditos = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->creditos));
              $this->clave_materia = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->clave_materia));
    
              // Bind data
              $stmt->bindValue(':nombre_materia', $this->nombre_materia);
              $stmt->bindValue(':semestre', $this->semestre);
              $stmt->bindValue(':creditos', $this->creditos);
              $stmt->bindValue(':clave_materia', $this->clave_materia);
    
              // Execute query
              if($stmt->execute()) {
                return true;
              }
    
              // Print error if something goes wrong
              printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    
              return false;
        }
    
        // Delete Post
        public function delete() {
              // Create query
              $query = 'DELETE FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE clave_materia = :clave_materia';
    
              // Prepare statement
              $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
              // Clean data
              $this->clave_materia = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->clave_materia));
    
              // Bind data
              $stmt->bindParam(':clave_materia', $this->clave_materia);
    
              // Execute query
              if($stmt->execute()) {
                return true;
              }
    
              // Print error if something goes wrong
              printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    
              return false;
        }
        
      }
```

Error:

```
Connection Error: could not find driver<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/models/Materias.php: 24
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/api/materias/read.php(17): Materias-&gt;read()
#1 {main
}
  thrown in <b>/var/www/html/models/Materias.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />

**bd connection**


<?php 
  class Database {
    // DB Params
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $db_name = 'reticula';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = 'test ';
    private $conn;

    // DB Connect
    public function connect() {
      $this->conn = null;

      try { 
        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }

      return $this->conn;
    }
  }
```

**This is where you call matters**

```
<?php 
  // Headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/Materias.php';

  // Instantiate DB & connect
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

  // Instantiate blog post object
  $materias = new Materias($db);

  // Blog post query
  $result = $materias->read();
  // Get row count
  $num = $result->rowCount();

  // Check if any posts
  if($num > 0) {
    // Post array
    $materias_arr = array();
    // $posts_arr['data'] = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      extract($row);

      $materias_item = array(
        'clave_materia' => $clave_materia,
        'nombre_materia' => $nombre_materia,
        'semestre' => $semestre,
        'creditos' => $creditos
      );

      // Push to "data"
      array_push($materias_arr, $materias_item);
      // array_push($posts_arr['data'], $post_item);
    }

    // Turn to JSON & output
    echo json_encode($materias_arr);

  } else {
    // No Posts
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'No Posts Found')
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where is the code that opens the database connection?

Comment: hello friend nice to meet you, I already added the part of the connection with db :)

Comment: Please do not do this `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags` on variables going into your database. This will damage your data.

Comment: Show how you're calling `Materias()`. The error implies that you passed `NULL` for the `$db` argument.